# Jacoco parameterize violation rule value

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco

I have the below content in my build.gradle file. I'm trying to fail the build if the coverage falls below a certain value.

```
project.task(type: JacocoCoverageVerification, "jacocoTestCoverageVerification", overwrite: true) {

    executionData(junitPlatformTestTask)
    sourceSets(sourceSets.main)
    sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.output)
    onlyIf = {
        true
    }
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                counter = 'INSTRUCTION'
                value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                minimum = 0.001
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I parameterize the value for "minimum" here so that I can pass it through Jenkins or Team city when building the project. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parametric build in Jenkinks, there add parameter "minimumValue". And then you could use it in build.gradle:

```
task jacocoJupTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    executionData(test)
    sourceSets(sourceSets.main)
    sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.output)

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        xml.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/report.xml")
        html.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
    }

    jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        violationRules {
            rule {
                limit {
                    counter = 'INSTRUCTION'
                    value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                    minimum = project.properties["minimumValue"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was, how I can pass that "0.001" as a parameter rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: you could do it by using gradle properties/environment variables/many other solutions

Comment: look at answer, I added example of one of possible solution

Comment: This will not work properly if you have excluded packages/classes on bundle level statistic evaluation. So, if we specify `element = CLASS`, we may only operate on `class`-level statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System environment to pass the parameters from Jenkins

`System.getEnv("<JENKINS_PARAM_NAME>") as String ?: "<default value>"`

make the type as `String` to have a safe assumption of the accepted param types in Jenkins. Then convert into the specific type back in gradle:

ex:

```
def coverageRatio = System.getEnv("COVERAGE_RATIO") as String ?: "1.0" //"default value is 100% coverage"
def fileFilter = ['**/path/to/your/classes/you/like/to/exclude','**/some/class']



violationRules {
    ...
    rule {
        element = 'BUNDLE'
        limit {
            counter = 'INSTRUCTION'
            value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
            minimum = coverageRatio.toBigDecimal()
        }
        excludes = fileFilter
    }

}
```